# Mongodb write concern in javascript update script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to write some update script for data via js, so is it possible to set for save or update operations write concern, the way it could be done in java driver?
Didn't find any docs about write concern in scripting for mongodb.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like `db.getLastError()`.

In Java/PHP/Python/etc, when you do `WriteConcern.Safe` or `safe => true`, you're actually doing a write command followed by a `getLastError` command. You can simulate that by using `db.getLastError()`.

Please note that there are currently two MongoDB documents regarding shell scripting. The first is the [Interactive Shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell), which is the shell you're probably used to. In that shell, all commands are issued in "safe" mode by default. The other document regards [scripting the shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell), which has some specific issues (including that getLastError).

Definitely check out that second document to run script this way. Also note that basically all of the functionality available to the shell is available to the drivers. So if you have scripting skills in Python or you're comfortable writing Windows Services, these can also be used for managing the server.

Comment: Thx, yes i that i was searching for